# YouTube API v3.0 VideoReponse and ListRequest class

Tags: api, youtube

Using the first example, found here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

for the .Net YouTube 3.0 API, I'm doing something very similar but using a VideoResource object not a SearchResource. Code from the example:

```
  YoutubeService youtube = new YoutubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
    ApiKey = credentials.ApiKey
  });

  SearchResource.ListRequest listRequest = youtube.Search.List("snippet");
  listRequest.Q = CommandLine.RequestUserInput<string>("Search term: ");
  listRequest.Order = SearchResource.Order.Relevance;

  SearchListResponse searchResponse = listRequest.Fetch();
```

Notice after setting the fields on the ListRequest object a Fetch() method is called to initialize a SearchListResponse object. However, this Fetch() method does not appear to be part of the API! What gives? Does anyone know how to execute the listrequest so that it returns a ListReponse object?

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `listRequest.Fetch();` try to use `listRequest.Execute();`

Comment: It does not have execute either.

Comment: Do you figure this out? I am having the same problem.